# La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo

Tags: laravel, sql-server

Quiero ejecutar una migracion con sus respectivos seeders de dos tablas
Users y Mail

La migracion de la tabla users tiene entre otros campos los, siguientes de tipo Fecha

```
           $table->datetime('email_verified_at')->nullable();
           $table->timestamps();
```

La migración de la tabla mails tiene los siguientes campos, entre otros

```
            $table->datetime('fecha_radicado');
            $table->timestamps();
```

En el Factory de Mail tengo lo siguiente

```
$factory->define(App\Mail::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'radicado' => $faker->randomDigit,
    'fecha_radicado' => now(),
    'destinatario' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 6, $variableNbWords = true),
    'cargo' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 6, $variableNbWords = true),
    'concepto' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 6, $variableNbWords = true),
    'remitente' => $faker->firstNameMale,
    'anexos' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 6, $variableNbWords = true)
];
```

});

En SQL SERVER Cuando ejecuto SELECT SYSDATETIME() Sale lo siguiente

```
2019-01-27 15:36:21.2896375
```

En el Modelo User y Mail Puse el siguiente codigo

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

Cuando ejecuto la migración y el seeder sale el siguiente error

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo. (SQL: insert into [mails] ([radicado], [fecha_radicado], [destinatario], [cargo], [concepto], [remitente], [anexos], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (5, 2019-01-27 15:58:48.250, Reiciendis distinctio ea fugiat culpa cum., Tenetur libero illum repellendus., Odit corrupti repellat est dolorum voluptate., Khalil, Aut aut saepe sunt dolorem assumenda ut., 2019-01-27 15:58:48, 2019-01-27 15:58:48))
```

Comment: El problema está en el seeder. Si te fijas, estas tratando de ingresar un entero en la columna mails, una fecha en radicado y un texto en fecha_radicado. No están coincidiendo los campos. Debes comprobar que los campos del seeder se correspondan con los de tu migración.  Saludos!

Comment: En el modelo quitar los guiones de la fecha protected $dateFormat = 'Ymd H:i:s';

Answer (score 1):

Tenia el mismo error,

Lo solucione sin usar "protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';"  en el modelo.

Lo que hice fue crear un nuevo usuario en sql server, dentro de security, logins, new login

[image: Nuevo usuario llamado "laravel"]

Este nuevo usuario debe tener seleccionado como lenguaje por defecto English-us

como se muestra en la imagen
[image: cambiar a english]

Con esto probé correr de nuevo la migración y funciono, como observación importante estoy usando Laravel Framework 8.46.0

Espero que a alguien le sirva.

Comment: A mi me funcionó, estoy usando Laravel 10.10

Answer (score 0):

Hola mi solucion para este problema con la fecha y el lenguaje de la DB es modificar el comportamiento del PDO con

```
//'encoding' => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8,
    'settings' => array(
        'DATEFORMAT' => 'ymd', // Make sure the date format is the right one
        'LANGUAGE' => 'us_english' // Not sure anymore if this is necessary for that problem, too
    ),
```

Yo tenia mi DB MSSQL en ingles, pero en remoto en Español y force que la DB en español trabaja como en ingles la fecha y solucione el problema de insert o update.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un
> valor fuera de intervalo.